# How can I create tips on how to use site ONLY on the user's first time logging in?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tooltip

I'm looking for some guidance on the most simplest way I can create hints/tips to appear on a website I'm working on, only on the user's FIRST time of logging in successfully. Then once the user chooses to close the tooltips/hints down, for it not to appear again. The tips would just be on how to use a site, what you normally see on apps nowadays.

I've tried googling it online and I'm probably not searching the correct terms.

What is the easiest way to do this?

What language would I need to use?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Personally I would use the existence or lack of a cookie. Maybe generate a signup cookie only when the account is created, and if JS detects that cookie, it shows signup tips. This cookie expires after an hour/day/whenever, and since it's not there, JS doesn't show tooltips. Try that?

Comment: could be a flag on the actual user, so once they log in update user with `hasLoggedIn: true`... then when they log in if that flag is false show the tips.

Comment: Thank you all so much, this is great stuff :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logical explanation:**

You can create an additional filed on users table, e.g: is_visited.
You can set default value for this field **'No'**,

Now check if current user's is_visited field is 'No' then show Introduction.
and Make is_visited field to 'Yes'

then next time for this user this check will false. and introduction will run only one time for every user...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I will pop another field in the users table and do this :-) not sure how but I can now see the logic behind it.

Comment: My pleasure, Sure, do try first, if stuck in coding, You can share your code too...

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this in the past was by creating a new column in the users table called last_login_at.

If last_login_at is null or empty by the time a user logs in, then I show the tips and update last_login_at with the current timestamp. If it is not empty, then I just update last_login_at with the current timestamp and move on. Next time the user logs in, last_login_at will already be set and the tips will not be shown again.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, these both seem great, so I will try these out and see if I can work them :-)